# What are your steps for setting up a guitar?

Tags: guitar, strings, setup

I'm just wondering what the ideal steps are to set up a guitar.
For instance, it needs a complete setup, you're changing the string gauge, setting the action, getting it intonated.
I'm not asking about more technical issues like changing pots, electronic issues etc., more just in relation to strings and getting it playing well and in tune.

Answer (score 11):

- Change strings, bring it up to tune, leave it or a couple of days.
- Check neck relief, change using truss rod if necessary.
- Change action height to preferred, by adjusting bridge/saddles height.
- Check intonation against 12th and 19th (and 24th if there) frets using harmonics.
- Re-tune. Leave to settle for a couple more days, while playing it.
- Go through it all again.

Comment: for curiosity: why leave it for a couple of days?

Comment: to let the new tension on the neck set in. The guitar doesn't fully adjust to the new tension instantly

Comment: If you want the guitar to play along with equal temperament instruments, it would be better to check and adjust intonation using a chromatic tuner. Harmonics are just intonated notes, and do not match the equal temperament notes. In addition to that, I've noticed on my guitars I can't have the intonation be totally accurate across the whole fretboard, so it may make sense to check and adjust intonation to match most closely at the frets one plays at most often. For me that's the 7th through 10th frets on electrics and the 1st through 5th frets on acoustic.

Comment: How do I know whether I need to adjust my truss rod or the bridge? How do I know when my truss rod is good for the guitar and how do I get the strings intonated all over the neck, not just with the harmonics. Are there any tools to set the best neck for the guitar?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Although that's technically true in general, the 12th fret harmonic is very nearly equal to the octave, and the 19th fret harmonic is less than 2 cents off an octave plus a fifth. It's common for chromatic tuners to have accuracy somewhere in the +/- 3 cent range, so using the harmonics here is not likely to result in measurable differences.

Comment: @random10101010 I think those subsequent questions are separate questions that might best be asked separately.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I'm interested as to how you adjust the intonation using a tuner.

Comment: One really importand part if changing string gauge:  check the Nut still holds the strings at a good height. Eg if you're going from .09 to .010 strings, the low E will be quite a lot thicker and probably sti too high in the nut, making F chords (or anything on 1st fret) difficult to play and sounding usually quite awful

Comment: @user2808054 - when you consider that there is 1/1000" difference between .009 and .010, and a human hair is somewhere between .003 and .005", there's not much to worry about. Most nuts will accommodate .008 - .011" with no consequences, and they're usually parallel sided, not tapered.

Comment: @Tim Use the tuner to make sure the open note is in tune. Fret the string near where you play the most and use the tuner to see if the fretted note is in tune. If the open note is in tune and the fretted note is not, adjust the bridge/saddle position accordingly. Repeat. Same thing as doing it with harmonics, except comparing to the tuner instead of to the harmonic.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - that'll work for someone who inhabits a particular area of the fingerboard, as you say. For me, anywhere between open and 15/17 fret is usable territory, so it's probably best I stick with harmonics. With a higher action, your idea may be more suitable given that a note will be slightly out anyway when fretted, due to being stretched.

Comment: @Tim ok - but fyi thats not my experience. The thicker strings vary by more (eg 46 on .010, .42 on .009)

Comment: @user2808054 - true, I only considered the top string! But there's only four thou difference between the bottoms - the width of a hair.

Answer (score 5):

Depending how far you might want to get into this, there are some books by author-guitar tech Dan Erlewine on guitar maintenance and setup that explain in detail, step by step, along with what tools are needed, and how to deal with problems one might encounter in the process of doing a set-up. I found his books very helpful when I started setting up my own guitars and when I have a problem, I still refer back to them.

Comment: We often suggest that folks put a link (if only to amazon) to an online source of the book recommended; that would improve your answer quality.